# IE8 doesn't render correctly pages from IIS8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, compatibility, iis-8

This is a kinda generic question so I don't have any specific code to post. Our ASP.NET 3.5 application has to support multiple browsers, including IE8+. And it does so - if the backend IIS server is below 8. If we try to browse a site installed on IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012) from IE8 - page renders incorrectly, styling is wrong, dimensions screwed etc.

This is not happening if IIS8 site is browsed with any other browser (including IE9 & IE10) OR if IE8 browses sites installed on IIS 7.5 and below. So the only combination IIS8/IE8 doesn't work. I understand that those 2 are quite a few years apart, but what could be the reason for this behavior - feel free to downvote, but I could use a few starting pointers.

Tracing HTTP calls shows that all pages, CSS and JS load normally. All our pages have `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`. No errors are thrown either server-side or client-side.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any significant headers in the HTTP requests that could explain the difference between IIS 7.5 and IIS 8?

Comment: Hit F12. What document mode is the page rendering in? Any messages on the Console when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Pages render in IE8 Standards mode, and headers are standard for requests to ASP.NET pages, nothing unusual. No error messages and I don't think IE8 dev tools have console (unless I missed it)